# With OpenAI universe, how do I display games in X11 when running universe from within docker?

Tags: docker, openai-gym

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 as my development environment. When I install OpenAI universe and all the pre-reqs directly into Ubuntu, I am able to run the “Run your first agent” script (https://github.com/openai/universe) and get an X window showing me the game.

When I build the docker image containing universe from the included Dockerfile (https://github.com/openai/universe/blob/master/Dockerfile) and run it with the same script, no pop-up appears. I am able to view the game by opening a web browser and viewing it over VNC, but this is not ideal for me.

I’m currently using the following commands to try and get the game to appear on my screen, but to no avail:

```
xhost +
XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix
XAUTH=/tmp/.docker.xauth
touch $XAUTH
chmod 644 $XAUTH
xauth nlist :0 | sed -e ‘s/^…/ffff/’ | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
docker run --privileged --rm -e DOCKER_NET_HOST=172.17.0.1 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $XSOCK:$XSOCK -v $XAUTH:$XAUTH -e XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH --v $PWD:/media universe python3 /media/test.py
```